# Parameters for my Azure Workbook was incorrect

Tags: powershell, azure, automation

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

$params = @{SqlServerName="myServer";SqlDatabaseName="myDb";SqlUserName="myDbUser"}

Register-AzureRmAutomationScheduledRunbook `
    –Name "AutoExport" `
    -ResourceGroupName "myAzureAutomation" `
    –AutomationAccountName "myAutomation" `
    –ScheduleName "myScedule" `
    –Parameters $params `
    -ErrorAction Stop;
```

And when I go on the Azure Portal parameters contain quoted string

Example:

[image: Azure Portal capture]

Eventually my Workbook will crash because values expected no quotes. I know, I can remove quotes into script of my Workbook but it seem to me that is not an elegant solution.

What I doing wrong!

Comment: this is weird, as a workaround, can you try to do `@{SqlServerName=$a;SqlDatabaseName="$b;SqlUserName=$c}`, where `$a,$b,$c` correspond to those values?

Comment: Same thing parameters always contain the quotes